# Display hotkey presses Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, hotkeys, on-screen-keyboard

Is there a way to display hotkey presses as they happen on screen in large text in Mac OS X Yosemite? Or is there an app that can do this?

I have tried “Sticky Keys.” They almost do this, but when the hotkey press is done it disappears immediately. I would like the hotkey press to stay on the screen until the next hotkey press. Sticky keys also don't display the character involved in the hotkey press.

I have also tried the “Show Keyboard Viewer.” This kind of works, but it’s hard to make out exactly which hotkey is pressed because there’s so much visual information on the keyboard. The key presses also don’t stick until the next key press.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[KeyCastr](https://github.com/keycastr/keycastr) seems like it does what you want.

From the Readme:

> KeyCastr, an open-source keystroke visualizer

Answer (score 2):

I’ve made an app for that too.  Take a look at **[Keystroke Pro](https://ixeau.com/apps/keystroke-pro/)**!

**Preview video**: https://youtu.be/3koqaw99uKA (30 sec)

**Download**: https://ixeau.com/apps/keystroke-pro/

[image]

**How to install it**:

1. Download the app: [Link](https://ixeau.com/apps/keystroke-pro/).
2. Unpack the `keystroke-pro.zip` archive you’ve just downloaded.
3. Drag the unpacked app to your applications directory.
4. Start the “Keystroke Pro” app.

**How to use it**:

- In order to detect keypresses the app needs to be added to the macOS Accessibility tab: `System Preferences...` > `Security & Privacy` > `Accessibility`
- You’re all set now. The app lives in your macOS status bar—you can activate it from there. Take a look at the [preview video](https://youtu.be/3koqaw99uKA) for further impressions.

Comment: Could you include a short tutorial on how to use this software? Please see [How to recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers)

Comment: @Burgi Dear Burgi—thanks for your hint. I just updated my answer. All the best, Martin